# Методы для добавление/удаление class'а

Tags: javascript, методы

Привет, ХэшКодовцы.

Подскажите методы для добавления и удаления class'а элементу с помощью js без всяких сторонних библиотек?

Comment: по-моему так, но могу ошибаться:

    var el = document.getElementById('id')
    el.className += ' className';

ещё есть вариант использовать [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList)

Comment: @Spectre, это я знаю. Меня интересует нормальное добавление/удаление классов с помощью встроенных методов.

Comment: Это оно и есть, если нужна кроссбраузерность

Comment: можно еще на jquery 

`$('selecter').addClass('class');
$('selecter').removeClass('class');`

Comment: ваш вариант особенно хорошо подходит под предложение:

>без всяких сторонних библиотек?

Comment: @Spectre, "ещё есть вариант использовать element.classList", спасибо, как раз то, что нужно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следующие две функции добавляют и удаляют класс DOM элемента.

```
function addClass(o, c){
    var re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + c + "(\\s|$)", "g")
    if (re.test(o.className)) return
    o.className = (o.className + " " + c).replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^ | $)/g, "")
}

function removeClass(o, c){
    var re = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + c + "(\\s|$)", "g")
    o.className = o.className.replace(re, "$1").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/(^ | $)/g, "")
}
```